# Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'CSSProperties'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

How to fix the `Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'CSSProperties'`

```
    const points = 100;
        const radius = 257;
        const max = 100;
        const peaks = [ 10, 50, 90 ];
        const step = (max + 1) / points;
        const realPeaks = peaks.map((peak) => Math.floor(peak * (1 / step)));
        const hueStep = 120 / points;
    const digit = props.item.temperature;
    const outerContainer = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < points; i++) {
    const intStep = Math.ceil(step * i);
            const intNextStep = Math.ceil(step * (i + 1));
    
            let styles = `transitionDelay: ${(i / digit * (i / digit) + 1)} +'s'`;
    
            if (intStep <= digit) {
                styles += `backgroundColor: hsl(${240 + i * hueStep} , 92%, 64%)`;
            }

***ADDEDD***
if (intStep > digit || (intStep <= digit && intNextStep <= digit)) {
            styles += `
        -webkit-transform: rotate(${degree}deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(${degree}deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(${degree}deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(${degree}deg);
        transform: rotate(${degree}deg);`;
        }
    outerContainer.push(<i className="bar" style={styles} />);
        }
```

What I'm trying to do here is to add the backgroundColor if `intStep <= digit`. but the ````` styles={styles}```` have an error which is the ````` Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'CSSProperties'```. How to fix on it.

I added a code for the transform

Answer (score 1):

You need an object instead of a string for the `styles` variable:

```
const styles: React.CSSProperties = {
    transitionDelay: `${(i / digit * (i / digit) + 1)} +'s'`
};
if (intStep <= digit) {
    styles.backgroundColor = `hsl(${240 + i * hueStep} , 92%, 64%)`;
}
```

Comment: ```Property 'backgroundColor' does not exist on type '{ transitionDelay: string; }'``` or I should use styles['backgroundColor']?

Comment: How'bout when I'm adding this ```-webkit-transform: rotate(${degree}deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(${degree}deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(${degree}deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(${degree}deg);
  transform: rotate(${degree}deg);`;```

Comment: Use bracket notation, eg ``styles['-webkit-transform'] = `rotate(${degree}deg)`;`` or define it inline with the object